# how to extend all contentpages using pagerenderer in UWP?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, custom-renderer

I would like to extend all the contentpages in my xamarin.forms app with a native view in UWP. I can basically go to each and every page and embed a native view but i dont want this. I want to know if there is a way to do it using a pagerenderer. I tried doing like below.

my idea was to get current page rendering and extend the content with native view and stacklayout and define app.content again with this change. It works in general. If you run the small test project below, you can see that native UWP FontIcons are displayed for each page but there is a problem, if i navigate same page 2 times in MasterDetail in the attached project, page becomes blank. Why is this happening?
and is the approach below best for my case? I am open for alternative solutions.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ContentPage), typeof(App3.UWP.ContentPageRenderer))]
namespace App3.UWP
{

    public class ContentPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {

        bool isDisposing = false;
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Page> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (isDisposing)
                return;

            if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
            {
                return;
            }


            ContentPage page = ((ContentPage)Element);
            if (page.Content == null)
                return;


            var XboxControls = new MyUserControl1();
            StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout() { Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical };
            stackLayout.Children.Add(page.Content);
            stackLayout.Children.Add(XboxControls.ToView());

            page.Content = stackLayout;

        }

        protected override Windows.Foundation.Size ArrangeOverride(Windows.Foundation.Size finalSize)
        {
            return base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            isDisposing = disposing;

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

    }
```

[Test Project](https://ufile.io/smkj5)

Comment: I don't think  it is  a good design that  re-layout all the content in your page render. I guess the page content was released when navigate to another page. And I captured the exception in your master listview `SelectionChanged` event. If you just want to add *watermark* for all the page, you could refer [Customizing a ContentPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/contentpage).

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT yes, basically i want to create a watermark for all contentpages when uwp app is running on Xbox. watermark, i created using natively and it should extend xamarin.forms contentpage in pagerenderer. i went through this example but it seems that it creates a complete new page natively rather than extending it. my solution works first time but when OnElementChanged is called 2nd time, it tries to extend again with same custom element and it throws exception as it is already part of the ui.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT so it would be ideal to either dispose and recreate the page or only extend 1 time. therefore since OnElementChanged called multiple times, it doesnt seem to be suitable for it.